# How to count the number of databases in mongod by mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I know how to list all databases in mongod. such as `db.getMongo().getDBNames()` `show dbs`. But how to count the number of databases?

Answer (score 7):

You almost got it already

`db.getMongo().getDBNames()` returns a JavaScript array, so to get the length of it, just do:

`db.getMongo().getDBNames().length`